# Another datasource for service layer unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, spring-data, spring-boot

After learning JUnit and experienced its benefits for both programmer and the project, I wanted now to unit test the service layer of each entities and test if each methods works properly.

As of now, I already have created a unit test for all of my service classes but the problem is that the datasource's data isn't suited for testing. Thus I have to created another database for service layer testing and configure the datasource for the unit test of the service layers. But the things is I don't know how to configure another datasource which only the `src/test/java` could access and couldn't be accessed upon production. I'm still new to SpringBoot and SpringData so I'm asking how to configure such requirements here.

As of now I have this `application.properties` configuration.

```
spring.datasource.url=<DatabaseURL>
spring.datasource.username=<DatabaseUsername>
spring.datasource.password=<DatabasePassword>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=<DatabaseDriver>
// another datasource configuration
```

And here's a sample code for a service class. Which uses the `application.properities - dataSource` configuration.

```
@Service
public class FooService {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Foo> findAllByFooForm(FooForm fooForm) {
        // JPA CriteriaBuilder query accroding to FooForm
        return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Finally, here's a sample code for unit test of a service class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class FooServiceTest {
    @AutoWired
    private FooService fooService

    @Test
    public void testFindAllByFooForm() {
        // Test statements
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few approaches which can be combined to give you good control over this.

First of all, if you create `src/test/resources/application.properties`, then that will only be available on the classpath during testing. It will override any properties that you have defined in `src/main/resouces/application.properties`.

If you are using an in-memory database to support those tests, then you can ensure that different `import.sql` files are loaded, through the use of the following property:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files=import-test1.sql
```

That annotation takes a comma-separated list of import scripts, so you can have a base set of data loaded by one script and additional (test-specific perhaps) data loaded by others.

If you wish to connect to a different database in each test, or cause different import scripts to be used, then you can use profiles to trigger this. If you create a properties file `application-test1.properties`, then the test itself can cause that to be loaded using the annotation: `@ActiveProfiles({"test1"})`.

Comment: Your suggestion worked very well. Unfortunately, Eclipse always shows me a warning `The resource is a duplicate of src/main/resources/application.properties and was not copied to the output folder`. Though the behaviour seems to be normal but is there another way to resolve this without the means of disable such warning to Eclipse?

Comment: I wouldn't know ... I don't do any builds in Eclipse. :)